# What methods are available for formatting text pragmatically for an info style display?

Tags: buffers, formatting

I want to create a temporary buffer and output some formatted text into the buffer, so indentation perhaps column type layouts.

I have written some lisp code that returns a load of lists so I want to loop over the lists outputting into a temporary buffer but displayed nicely ?

Something like this perhaps, the format is not that important its more a general question asking whats available are there any useful packages etc ?

```
List header 1           List header 2 
list 1 Item 1           list 2 Item 1            
    list 1 item2        list 2 Item 2
    list 1 item3        list 2 Item 3
    list 1 item4
```

I know I can use `(insert)` and perhaps thats what you do then work out the spacing yourself in a loop ?

Comment: Perhaps `tabulated-list-mode` is what you're after?  This is what's used by the likes of `package-list-packages` and `list-processes`

Comment: maybe so if I created a temporary buffer using `tabulated-list-mode` and use insert against may lisp list would it automatically be tabulated ?

Comment: See `C-h f tabulated-list-mode`

Comment: this is quite close, but seems geared towards rows of data instead of columns, still reading up about it so i could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, that was how I had interpreted your example. I expect you could still use it if you transformed your data accordingly, but maybe there's a better alternative.

Comment: yeah the example is just that, it's more a general question if you want to create an information style popup on how you would go about formatting / aligning your text. what I am after at the moment is two columns with different sized lists displayed in the columns. But just an idea on whats out there would be nice I could not find much online.